# Ignore child hrefs when a click event is present on the parent

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to attach an event handler **to the parent element** in the following snippet that will stop the child's href or click handlers from firing. I'd like to avoid finding all of the children, because there may be different click handlers present on them. Is this possible, and how could it be achieved?

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
parent.onclick = e => {
  console.log('parent clicked')
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

const child = document.querySelector('a')
child.onclick = () => console.log('child clicked')
```

```css
.parent {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="stackoverflow.com"/>Hello there</a>
<div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add `.parent * { pointer-events: none; }` to the CSS?

Comment: I'd like to do it with javascript, because it should be dynamic. But I was going to go down this route (attaching a class to the parent) if I can't think of any other way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let parentClicked = false;

const parent = document.querySelector('.parent')
parent.onclick = e => {
  parentClicked = true;
  console.log('parent clicked')
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

const child = document.querySelector('a')
child.onclick = (e) => {
  if (parentClicked) e.preventDefault();
}
```

If that doesn't work then set the child element's disabled property to `"true"` or `"on"`, I forget which one.

But that way you can dynamically set it's disabled property with JavaScript.